# Simplify a combinatorial sum

Tags: combinations

Why is $\sum_{k=0}^n (_k^n) 2^k$ simplified as $3^n$ and not just $2^n$ ?
The answer uses the binomial theorem as a solution: let $a=1$ and let $b=2$. So $1+2 = 3$. But since $1+2 = 3$ why do we not use $1+1 = 2$?